# Jaxb: How to specify a default class for an XSD element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

When generating Java classes from a XSD, how can I specify that for some specific node, a specific and already existent Java class should be used instead of trying to generate one?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `episode` file to reference the existing classes. `.episode` files are just `jaxb` bindings file and has mappings between elements and java classes.

**a)** if those existing classes are also generated from (another) xsd. use below option to first create .episode file.

```
xjc -episode a.episode a.xsd
```

then use this `a.episode` that contains the mappings as input to the next `xjc` generation.

```
xjc b.xsd -extension -b a.episode
```

**b)** If you want to refer some random classes, then you may have to write your own episode file providing mapping between `element` and `class reference` like below.

**sample.episode**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" if-exists="true" version="2.1">
 <jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::">
    <jaxb:bindings scd="employee">
      <jaxb:class ref="www1.example.Employee"/>
      <jaxb:package name="www1.example" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
```

and use `xjc b.xsd -extension -b sample.episode`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is for the 2+ version, do you know if it is possible to do it for Jaxb2 version 1.6?

Comment: welcome!. yes it is possible using JDK 1.6 (update latest). Refer this [matrix](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use following binding customization

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix">
    <bindings schemaLocation="../schema/yourSchema.xsd">

        <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Foo']">
            <class ref="com.FooImpl"/> 
        </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```